# How do i store cookies in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to store some values in browser using cookies

but i don't do i do ?

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.

- Using [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary) and javascript.

  > The `ExternalInterface` class is the External API, an application programming interface that enables straightforward communication between ActionScript and the Flash Player container– for example, an HTML page with JavaScript. Adobe recommends using `ExternalInterface` for all JavaScript-ActionScript communication.
- Using local [SharedObjects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) from within Flex

> The `SharedObject` class is used to read and store limited amounts of data on a user's computer or on a server. Shared objects offer real-time data sharing between multiple client SWF files and objects that are persistent on the local computer or remote server. Local shared objects are similar to browser cookies and remote shared objects are similar to real-time data transfer devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this library called *JSinterface* on GoogleCode

http://code.google.com/p/jsinterface/